# Why does Windows form get shrink after ms access database connection has build up? How to solve It?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

[before connecting to database(FORM IS RUNNING BUT DATA IS NOT CONNECTED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOOSl.png)

[after connecting to database(FORM IS RUNNING NOW DATA IS CONNECTED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL1RR.png)
I am using MS Access database in a C# Windows Form application. When I run the application and as database connection builds up, the form gets shrinks. All things on form get small. Whats the reason behind this and How can I fix it?

Screenshots:
[image: IMAGE1 BEFORE SHRINKING] 
[image: IMAGE2 AFTER SHRINKING]

//MyCodePart1

public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
       static string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\AppDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"; // WORKING

```
    OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(conString);
    OleDbCommand command;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    public Form1() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Century", 12F, FontStyle.Bold);



        lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //FetchID();
        //SerialAutoGenerate();
        //FetchMethod();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; // FORM MAXIMIZED

    }
```

//FETCH DATA METHOD FOR FETCHING DATA INTO DATAGRIDVIEW

public void FetchData()
{

```
        try
        {

            String query = "Select * from CUS_DETAILS";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myCon);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            myCon.Open();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
            myCon.Close();

            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

//FetchData Button for Both DataGridView

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
        FetchMethod();//fetching data into datagridview1
        FetchData(); //fetching data into datagridview2
```

}

Comment: Let's see a screenshot--before the shrinkage and after the shrinkage...

Comment: I have uploaded the both images.

Comment: Just wondering if you are talking about clicking on the `Maximise` button in the top right corner of the window. If I understood you correctly, it looks like the data editors have fixed length and do not expand to the right after the window maximisation. Check the properties of the controls to see their behaviour and sizes.

Comment: @oleksii I don't know what's happening, but i have set the Windows State property to Maximized, i don't click on it in runtime. I have loaded the all data into datagrid on the Form_Load Event and as it connected to database and loaded the data, all controls on the form get changes into small. As you can compare the both images,Before shrinking DataGrid size is looking bigger(at time of designing)  and in the after shrinking image it is small. I hope you are getting my point. Thanks

Comment: @oleksii: The controls are definitely smaller--that is, their width/height values are less in the "after" image versus the "before" image. More is going on than editors not scaling-up after maximize, agreed?

Comment: @stillcoder: You have reported that this is happening after "database connection builds up" (not sure what that means), but then you show two screen images--one restored and one maximized. So you concluded that this issue is related to DATA when it appears to be related only to the UI. What happens if you start with the empty form (image 1) and just maximize it before you do anything with data? Does it also "shrink"? Did you hook into the maximize event for the form? Can we see what code you might have there???

Comment: @Jazimov No, Form does not shrink before connecting to database. It remains same as i designed it (All height and width do remain same). And image1(before shrinking image) is the screenshot of my designed form. I do not maximize the form at runtime, i have set it to maximized in the property window. When form runs it already maximized.

Comment: @Jazimov I am unable to understand this whether this is a problem of UI or a data connection, but this happens after the data is connected, i will share two more images and my code with you.

Comment: @Jazimov Should I post all the code or screenshot of code? This is a testing purpose code so it is not a clean code.

Comment: I have uploaded two more images, Now Compare them,I hope now you can get my issue. I don't know the exact cause but its happening after data connected. Thanks

Comment: I have shared some part of code. Please ignore my poor coding sense. :)

Comment: I don't know how it done, but i got the solution. I was trying different ways to fix it. I did two changes (one to my form properties, and second to my pc display setting) and it done.
First i changed my form's AutoScaleMode to dpi and then 
i changed my pc display setting to 1600x900, this was set to 1920x1080 and after connected to database now form is as it is as i was designe it.

Comment: If you guys can explain how it done, please do. Thanks all for your precious time.